# How to see if Docker daemon is Docker Desktop or not

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm writing a CLI that creates containers. Due to the cross platform nature of the CLI and various quirks with Docker networking, I've found it is easiest to decide how to configure networking based on whether the Docker daemon comes from Docker Desktop or not.

The way I'm doing this now is essentially the following:

```bash
$ docker info -f json | jq -r .Name
docker-desktop
```

This `Name` field is described as `Hostname of the host` but in practice I've found that when using Docker Desktop, the value of this field is always `docker-desktop`.

I worry that this isn't that reliable and may change at some point. Is there a more reliable way to determine whether the Docker daemon comes from Docker Desktop or not?

Comment: What networking details would be different for Docker Desktop?  Would you need to account for other environments, like using a Minikube VM as a Docker environment?

Comment: Mainly that with Docker Desktop you can use host.docker.internal out of the box whereas with other Docker environments you have to use something else.

Comment: Tuns out this field was indeed not reliable, it shows up as linuxkit something or other despite using Docker Desktop. Now I'm using the Operating System field, let's see how that goes.