# How to access service running on host from inside Docker container in a cross platform way without using a bridge?

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-for-mac

I have read every answer to these two questions and more:

- [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)
- [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container)

I have a CLI that runs some services natively on `127.0.0.1` on a variety of ports on the host system. It also spins up Postgres in a container and exposes it at `127.0.0.1:5432` on the host.

Once this is done, the CLI spins up a new container that connects to Postgres.

I want a single invocation for running this final container that works across all host platforms. In particular:

- MacOS (Docker Desktop)
- Windows (WSL) (Docker Desktop)
- Windows (native aka NT kernel) (Docker Desktop)
- Linux (Docker Desktop)

Based on the first question above, it seems like it should be possible to connect to `host.docker.internal` from inside the container on all platforms if I run the container like this. Assume the binary in the container knows where to connect to based on this `ADDR` env var:

```
docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway -e ADDR=host.docker.internal:5432 my_image
```

The `--add-host` flag isn't necessary under the Docker Desktop environment but on Linux, this is necessary to let the container access the host. In reality, this only works on Linux with `--network host`. I can see from the logs that the name resolution works successfully (it tries to connect to `172.17.0.1` from within the container) but the connection fails without `--network host`, perhaps due to some permission issue (I run as root on Linux). Problem is, if I use `--network host` with Docker for Desktop, it fails to connect.

Assume I cannot solve this by creating a custom network, using bridge networking, and that I must bind all services both in and not in containers to `127.0.0.1`.

Currently I'm solving this by having the CLI figure out if Docker Desktop is in use and changing the command accordingly:

- Without Docker for Desktop use `--network host` and connect to `127.0.0.1` from within the container.
- With Docker for Desktop do not use `--network host` and connect to `host.docker.internal` from within the container.

Issue is I'm finding the detection of whether the host is Docker for Desktop or not quite flaky: [How to see if Docker daemon is Docker Desktop or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77243960/how-to-see-if-docker-daemon-is-docker-desktop-or-not).

In all cases I'm using Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b.

Comment: Postgres is listening for connections on `0.0.0.0:5432` inside the container, which I then bind to the host at `127.0.0.1:5432`. I have confirmed that I can connect to postgres in the container with `psql` from the host, so that's not the issue. Despite that, from the second container I see this error: 
`{"error":"connection error","path":"$","code":"postgres-error","internal":"connection to server at \"host.docker.internal\" (172.17.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?\n"}`

Comment: This comment was in response to a couple of comments that have now disappeared btw hahah ^

Comment: I'd say the most portable way to do this is to also run the database in a container.  Getting the database installed and configured correctly can be tricky and host-specific as well, and again whether the host database is reachable is a platform-specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fundamentally trying to connect from one container to another.  This doesn't require anything special at the host level.  You should not be using `host.docker.internal` or host networking to try to connect from one container to another.

The basic mechanism here is described in [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname): if you create a Docker network and you make sure both containers are on the same network, then one container's name will be usable as a host name from the other container.  This is fully portable across all host operating systems and Docker setups.

For example, this could look like

```bash
# Create a Docker network
docker network create a-network

# Start the database container
#   Attach it to a-network
#   Publish its port on the host's localhost interface
docker run \
  -d \
  --name a-database
  --net a-network \
  -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
  -v a-database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres:15

# Start the application container
#   Attach it to a-network
#   Specify the database container's name as the database name
docker run \
  --net a-network \
  -e ADDR=a-database:5432
  my_image
```

The `a-network`, `a-database`, `a-database-data` names need to match each other within a particular invocation, but in the context of a CLI tool like you're discussing it could be reasonable to generate unique names for these per invocation.

This setup seems to meet your requirements: the database is accessible from outside Docker, but only on the same host; the application can connect to the database; the setup is independent of any particular Docker distribution.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize it was possible to use a Docker network but still publish to the host. Let me take this for a spin!

Comment: The other important caveat here: the Docker-network connection to the database container _always_ uses the standard port, for PostgreSQL port 5432.  If you remap the published port by changing the first `docker run -p` port number, this doesn't affect connections between containers.

Comment: I tried this and like you say, it meets all my requirements. It even works when the CLI is running from within a container and using the Docker API through a socket I bound to the container, which was another thing I needed. Great!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was running with this configuration:

- Postgres binds to 0.0.0.0 inside the container.
- I publish that to 127.0.0.1 on the host.

The solution was to publish to 0.0.0.0 on the host instead. In other words, when running the Postgres container, do this:

```bash
--publish 0.0.0.0:5432:5432
```

Instead of this:

```bash
--publish 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
```

Why this is necessary I'm not quite sure, but it works!

Comment: Your question implies the database isn't running in a container but is running directly on the host.  You shouldn't need `host.docker.internal` to connect from one container to another.  How are you launching the two containers?

Comment: I mention in the question "It also spins up Postgres in a container". Given that, do you have a different suggestion than connecting through the host network?

Comment: If you create a Docker network, then [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname) will work for you.  If you're using Compose this is set up automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to bind my services to 127.0.0.1 so a custom network won't suffice in this case I think.

Comment: ...to the per-container private localhost interface?  That usually means the services are completely unreachable from outside their own containers.

Comment: I need the services running within the containers to be accessible from the host at 127.0.0.1. So, they bind to 0.0.0.0 within the container and then I publish the port on 127.0.0.1 on the host.